# RenderScript runs slower than Kotlin on simple array adding

Tags: android, kotlin, renderscript

Array adding should benefit from parallel computing a lot, since every element can do the compute simultaneously. However, RenderScript which suppose to use all CPU and GPU cores runs slower than Kotlin which uses only 1 CPU core (because I didn't create multiple thread). This is the case for all array sizes.

```
D: ======== 100 by 100 matrix add (10 times) ========
D: Average time RS: 0.0022388910000000002
D: Average time Kotlin: 2.3658340000000004E-4
D: First run RS: 0.004244063
D: First run Kotlin: 5.59219E-4
D: Best time RS: 0.0014166670000000001
D: Best time Kotlin: 5.2291000000000005E-5
D: Worst time RS: 0.004244063
D: Worst time Kotlin: 0.001291354
D: ======== 300 by 300 matrix add (10 times) ========
D: Average time RS: 0.0054014956
D: Average time Kotlin: 4.6969260000000006E-4
D: First run RS: 0.00759224
D: First run Kotlin: 4.19635E-4
D: Best time RS: 0.003174324
D: Best time Kotlin: 4.19635E-4
D: Worst time RS: 0.009118335
D: Worst time Kotlin: 5.57552E-4
D: ======== 1000 by 1000 matrix add (10 times) ========
D: Average time RS: 0.0152955638
D: Average time Kotlin: 0.006399682700000001
D: First run RS: 0.019055053000000002
D: First run Kotlin: 0.008983386000000001
D: Best time RS: 0.011003751
D: Best time Kotlin: 0.0054310420000000005
D: Worst time RS: 0.019055053000000002
D: Worst time Kotlin: 0.008983386000000001
```

For every matrix size I run 10 times, first time is always the slowest, so I specifically print it out.

I want to know why Kotlin runs faster than RenderScript, and how to improve the performance of RenderScript so it can run much faster than Kotlin like it suppose to do.

It was tested on a Pixel 3a.

RenderScript code

```
//singlesource.rs

#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(MY_PACKAGE_NAME)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

float RS_KERNEL _add(float in1, float in2) {
    return in1 + in2;
}

void add(rs_allocation output, rs_allocation mat1, rs_allocation mat2) {
    rsForEach(_add, mat1, mat2, output);
}
```

Kotlin code

```
class Matrix(var data: FloatArray, var width: Int) {
    fun add(rs: RenderScript, s: ScriptC_singlesource?, another: Matrix): Matrix {
        val newData = vecAdd(rs, s, data, another.data)
        return Matrix(newData, width)
    }

    fun slowAdd(another: Matrix): Matrix {
        val newData = FloatArray(data.size)
        for (i in data.indices) {
            newData[i] = data[i] + another.data[i]
        }
        return Matrix(newData, width)
    }

    companion object {
        fun vecAdd(rs: RenderScript, s: ScriptC_singlesource?, vecA: FloatArray, vecB: FloatArray) : FloatArray {
            val script = s ?: ScriptC_singlesource(rs)
            val aAlloc: Allocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, Type.createX(rs, Element.F32(rs), vecA.size))
            val bAlloc: Allocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, Type.createX(rs, Element.F32(rs), vecB.size))
            aAlloc.copyFrom(vecA)
            bAlloc.copyFrom(vecB)
            val outputAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, Type.createX(rs, Element.F32(rs), vecA.size))
            script.invoke_add(outputAllocation, aAlloc, bAlloc)
            val output = FloatArray(vecA.size)
            outputAllocation.copyTo(output)
            return output
        }
    }
}
```

Testing code

```
val rs: RenderScript = RenderScript.create(this)
val script = ScriptC_singlesource(rs)
val rounds = 10
val matrixSizes = arrayOf(100, 300, 1000)
for(s in matrixSizes) {
    var m1: Matrix
    var m2: Matrix
    val recordRs = DoubleArray(rounds)
    val recordKotlin = DoubleArray(rounds)
    Log.d("Performance", "======== $s by $s matrix add ($rounds times) ========")
    for(i in 0 until rounds) {
        m1 = Matrix(FloatArray(s*s) {Random.nextFloat()*2-1}, s)
        m2 = Matrix(FloatArray(s*s) {Random.nextFloat()*2-1}, s)
        var elapsed = measureNanoTime {
            m1.add(rs, script, m2)
        }
        recordRs[i] = elapsed*1e-9

        m1 = Matrix(FloatArray(s*s) {Random.nextFloat()*2-1}, s)
        m2 = Matrix(FloatArray(s*s) {Random.nextFloat()*2-1}, s)
        elapsed = measureNanoTime {
            m1.slowAdd(m2)
        }
        recordKotlin[i] = elapsed*1e-9
    }
    Log.d("Performance", "Average time RS: ${recordRs.average()}")
    Log.d("Performance", "Average time Kotlin: ${recordKotlin.average()}")
    Log.d("Performance","First run RS: ${recordRs[0]}")
    Log.d("Performance","First run Kotlin: ${recordKotlin[0]}")
    Log.d("Performance", "Best time RS: ${recordRs.minOrNull() ?: -1.0}")
    Log.d("Performance", "Best time Kotlin: ${recordKotlin.minOrNull() ?: -1.0}")
    Log.d("Performance", "Worst time RS: ${recordRs.maxOrNull() ?: -1.0}")
    Log.d("Performance", "Worst time Kotlin: ${recordKotlin.maxOrNull() ?: -1.0}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the ScriptC and Allocations in the Matrix's constructor
2. If applicable, move the copyTo calls for filling the input allocations also to the constructor
3. Increase repetitions by a lot.